# How to delete a selected row from datagridview and database ms access in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

Dear All Master,

I have tried but there is an error "no value given for one or some required parameters".

Is there something wrong with my code?

sorry my mistake because I want to tell "EMPID" that the datatype in ms access database is text and primary key

Thanks

```
 Public Sub jokendelete(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("No Data has been Updated!")
                    'Else
                    '    MsgBox("New Data is updated succesfully!")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        End Try
        con.Close()

    End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim selectedIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index

            Dim EMPID As Integer = Integer.Parse(DataGridView1(0, selectedIndex).Value.ToString())


            jokendelete("DELETE * FROM tblemployee where EMPID=@EMPID")
        End If

    End Sub
```

[datagridview selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izxyo.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

There are far better ways to delete records via a `DataGridView` but, specifically relating to the code you have, you have specified a `@EMPID` parameter in your `DELETE` statement but never provided a value for it to the command. Your code is pretty ugly from the point of view that you get the ID and SQL in one place and create the command in another but the simplest option would probably be to change this:

```vb
Public Sub jokendelete(ByVal sql As String)
```

to this:

```vb
Public Sub jokendelete(sql As String, empId as Integer)
```

and this:

```vb
jokendelete("DELETE * FROM tblemployee where EMPID=@EMPID")
```

to this:

```vb
jokendelete("DELETE * FROM tblemployee where EMPID=@EMPID", EMPID)
```

and this:

```vb
With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = sql
```

to this:

```vb
With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = sql
    .Parameters.Add("@EMPID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = empId
```

Of course, that method can now only be used for a SQL statement with that one specific parameter now. Fixing the overall structure of your code goes beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: sorry my mistake because I want to tell "EMPID" that the datatype in ms access database is text and primary key.

Comment: means I have to change my code please guide from you

Comment: @user18, if the value is text then don't convert it to an `Integer`. Use a `String`. That means changing the method parameter type from `Integer` to `String` and using a different `OleDbType` when adding the parameter. If the question you have asked is wrong then you should edit the question and then notify people of that change. No one should have to read the comments on an answer to understand the question.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested. " .Parameters.Add("@EMPID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = empId" and "Public Sub jokendelete(ByVal sql As String, empId As String)" . the database is not deleted, only a message box appears "No Data has been Updated!"

Comment: @user18, *"only a message box appears..."*. No, that's not all that happens. That's your message that you told your code to display if `ExecuteNonQuery` returns zero. If you execute a `DELETE` statement and the result is zero then obviously the PK you specified doesn't exist. That's not a problem with the code. That's a problem with you and how you're testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub jokendelete(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("No Data has been Updated!")
                    'Else
                    '    MsgBox("New Data is updated succesfully!")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        End Try
        con.Close()

    End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim EMPID As Integer = Integer.Parse(DataGridView1.CurrentRow("EmpID").Value)
           
        jokendelete("DELETE * FROM tblemployee where EMPID="& EMPID)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: While that will work in this case, it's rather bad advice to suggest to someone who is halfway to using parameters to dial it back and not use them at all.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 ,sorry my mistake because I want to tell "EMPID" that the datatype in ms access database is text and primary key.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 , Your code has an error ."Error BC32016 'Public Overloads ReadOnly Property CurrentRow As DataGridViewRow' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed."